# What does 虚怀若谷 mean?

Tags: translation

What does 虚怀若谷 mean? I'm learning some Chinese idioms and the translation that I was given was long and confusing, especially since my Mandarin isn't good. Can someone help me translate it?

Comment: http://www.ichacha.net/%20%E8%99%9A%E6%80%80%E8%8B%A5%E8%B0%B7.html
https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=+%E8%99%9A%E6%80%80%E8%8B%A5%E8%B0%B7  http://www.xiaoma.info/compound.php?cp=%E8%99%9A%E6%80%80%E8%8B%A5%E8%B0%B7&fhz=%20%E8%99%9A%E6%80%80%E8%8B%A5%E8%B0%B7

Comment: Here's what a dictionary gives: receptive as an echoing canyon (idiom); modest and open-minded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

虚 = empty

怀 = chest (metaphorically represents the storage place for beliefs and ideas in a man )

若 = like

谷 = valley ( a valley is vast and empty-- metaphor for one's mind not filled with preconceived notions )

> 虚怀若谷 means: 'one's ability to accept (new idea or different opinion) is as vast as a valley.'

In short, a man who is 虚怀若谷, is a **humble** and **open minded** man

Comment: No, I did not read the linked article. I answer the question base on my own impression and understanding on the phrase. Just fixed some spacing problem and added punctuation marks

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. I didn't read any comment before I edit this post.  I have a habit of reading my own posts after I posted them. When I find some mistakes or area I can improve, I would edit them accordingly. If I have to quote other comments or answers, I would also do so.

Comment: Someone suggested I should edit 虚 = empty to 虚 =modesty. I rejected the suggestion because 虚怀若谷 does mean "empty chest like valley' ; 虚 here isn't a short form of 謙虛

Answer (score 0):

谷(valley) is kind of metaphor, someone's mind is very open（like a valley）, it can fit a lot of different things
Very open minded, can accept all kinds of criticisms or compliments, and can identify their problems and correct them based on the criticisms. Doesn't get complacent with others' compliments.
it's also a kind of humble